# Regular Expression for decimal with optional (-) or (.) and limited total digits

Tags: java, regex

What would be the regular expression to check whether a string conforms to [-]n[.n], where n is any digit (1-9), with a minimum of 3 digits and maximum of 20? The "-" and/or "." should not be included within the digit count.

So far I have this:

```
^([-]?(?=.{3,21}$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

In large that pattern works, however as soon as you put an illegal character in, it will match everything up to that character. I.e.

```
-84.427345-388625
```

will match

```
-84.427345
```

however I need it to not match anything at that point. Which is what I can't seem to figure out at the moment.

It should also not match if there are any illegal characters before and/or after the number. The resultant regex needs to be compatible with the standard Java regex libraries.

Comment: Add `$` at the end.

Comment: use [`^([-]?(?=.{3,21}$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/R2JZ3d/1)

Comment: Can you show a code that you used?